# Idioms or phrases for "Be it good or bad"

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

Can you suggest some idioms or phrases for *Be it good or bad*? For example:

> **Be it good or bad**, television has become an indispensable part of our lives.

Comment: N.B. It is dispensable. I dispensed of it.

Comment: Be it good or bad *is* an idiom already.

Comment: That's just an archaic version of _Whether it's good or bad_. It used to be possible to use a fronted infinitive form of _be_ as a mark of a hypothetical clause. In Modern English we use subordinating conjunctions like _whether_ or _if_ to do the same job.

Comment: Could native English speakers teach me if "Anyway" is acceptable here?

Answer (score 6):

*[For better or worse](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/better_3)* is used to say that something cannot be changed, whether the result is good or bad.

Answer (score 0):

*For vice or virtue.* 
*For virtue or vice.*